# Integrate test process with Rspec and Cucumber in a plugin using Desert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rspec, cucumber

I'm developing some rails plugins with desert, and I would like to use tests with RSpec and Cucumber in the development. RSpec is integrated by default in Desert plugins, but it gives me some bugs.
Finally I have created a minimal application which use my plugin, and I try to test it like a normal application without plugin. But I dislike that solution, the plugin lost its modularity, and RSpec still returns me some bugs (he can't find the models/views/controllers located in the plugin...).
So am I the only one who try to test a Desert plugin (or even in a classic plugin) ? May anyone know those matters and get a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I was working with 'Desert' plug-ins in a legacy Rails 2.2.2 app and the following helped me http://pivotallabs.com/users/joe/blog/articles/985-testing-desert-plugins-in-isolation

Answer (score -1):

You should not use desert plugin, it's an 'old thing'.